# How do I find the files installed by a particular package? Where is the .deb file to look at?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have installed `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` using `apt`.

```bsh
$ type pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
bash: type: pulseaudio-module-bluetooth: not found
$ which pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
$ whereis pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:
```

Clearly, I'm looking for the wrong thing.  The package does not simply install a command that is the same name as the package.  Alright, then.

I want to find out what all commands (or executables) this package installed, and their locations.

The answers to "[How to get information about deb package archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187221/)" tell me how to find the files installed by the package *if I have a `.deb` file*.  I'm not installing directly from a `.deb` file, though.  I'm using `apt`.  Where is the `.deb` file that *that* used?  Is there a copy on my system somewhere that I can query with the commands in the answers to that question?  Where?

If there isn't a local copy on my system, can I get one with `apt`?  How?

Is there some handy `apt` (or similar) command that wraps this up for me, so that I do not have to run `dpkg-deb` directly?  What is it?

Can I find the package's file list entirely on-line, without explicitly downloading any `.deb` files and *before* installing anything with `apt`?  How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think there is an existing answer to your question (which isn’t [How to get information about deb package archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187221/86440)), but I can’t find it.

To list the contents of an *installed* package, use `dpkg -L`:

```
dpkg -L pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

If you want to list the contents of a package before installing it, install `apt-file`, then run `apt update`, and

```
apt-file list pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

will list the contents of the package without downloading it or installing it.

You can also view the contents of a package from [its web page](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth); look for “list of files” links at the bottom of the page.

Comment: On running the mentioned commands, I found that this package has only shared objects `.so`  files and documentation files. So, does this means that there is no associated executable? I was expecting an executable as in the description it says that it is a sound server for POSIX systems.

Comment: Also, in this case how can I make sure that the installed package is working properly? In this case wether the shared objects are being identified and used by the system?

Comment: The sound server is PulseAudio, which is installed by the `pulseaudio` package. `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` is a PulseAudio module. To check it’s being used, run `pactl list modules` and look for Bluetooth modules (`module-bluetooth-policy`, `module-bluetooth-discover`, `module-bluez5-discover`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a few approaches here. One of easiest is to download specific package:

```
cd /tmp/ && apt download pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

and list package content by:

```
dpkg -c pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-{version_stuff}.deb |grep bin
```

Comment: This answer is just complicating. Dpkg - L package_name is more than enough for listing the contents of installed packages

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - But would `pkg -c  <package>` list the contents?
Would it work on a non-installed package?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio apt download does not install a package, only downloads it to disk.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - Ok. Still, I did not understand from your comments (and I would appreciate clarifying) whether:
1) `dpkg -c <package>` would correctly list the contents of a `.deb` file.
2) it works on a non-installed package.
You mention this answer "is just complicating".
As I see it, this answer works just as well as the accepted answer, by listing the deb file corresponding to a package, instead of the package by its name. It may require a tiny plus of an effort...

Comment: @sancho IMO one complication is that this solution involves downloading the package just to list its contents. `apt-file list` doesn’t. If you have the package file already, then yes, `dpkg -c` works fine, without requiring the package to be installed.

Comment: @StephenKitt - That is correct. I think this is the point worth remarking as the main difference with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> I want to find out what all commands (or executables) this package
> installed, and their locations.

I found [this answer](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/do-i-need-usr-lib-debug-783100/#post3831598) from member [Evo2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/user/evo2-451341/) over at [linuxquestions.com](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/) where he mentions a nice utility called `dlocate`. `dlocate` has a nice "-lsbin" option which does exactly that. Since you mention `apt` I presume you are using a debian derivative, so `dlocate` should be available for your distro.

For example, if I want to find all executables shipped with libreoffice7.0 I'd do :

```
root#ychaouche-PC 14:15:15 /opt # dlocate -lsbin libreoffice7.0
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/minidump_upload
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/oosplash
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/soffice
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/soffice.bin
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/unoinfo
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/unopkg
/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/unopkg.bin
root#ychaouche-PC 14:19:44 /opt #
```

Please bare in mind that you need to do an `update-dlocate` in order for `dlocate` to work properly.